# How to create table dynamically

Tags: python, docx

I want to create table depending on user input value.

There are a max 7 column per table, with first column as name of row. When the user enters 9 values instead of 7, then it should create next table with two column. Then to those table i am giving value later in the prog from some computation.

I tried this code but getting error

```
vr={}
num=0
    for num in range(1,k):
        print site_count
        print 'num is',num

vr[str(num)]=document.add_table(rows=13, cols=(7))
print vr['1']

for num in range(1,k+1):
    vr['num'].cell(1, 0).text='Subscribed BW'
    vr['num'].cell(2, 0).text='Peak LAN'
    vr['num'].cell(3, 0).text='Peak WAN-IN'
    vr['num'].cell(4, 0).text='Peak WAN-OUT'
    vr['num'].cell(5, 0).text='Recommended BW Capacity'
    vr['num'].cell(7, 0).text='Peak Compression'
    vr['num'].cell(9, 0).text='Optimized Traffic'
    vr['num'].cell(10, 0).text='Optimized Traffic%'
    vr['num'].cell(12, 0).text='Key Applications'
    vr['num'].style ='TableGrid'
```

**ERROR as:**    vr['num'].cell(1, 0).text='Subscribed BW'
KeyError: 'num'

Is there any other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't str() unnecessarily, try the followig code

```
vr = {}
num = 0
vr[num]=document.add_table(rows=13, cols=(7))
print vr['1']

for num in range(1,k+1):
    vr[num].cell(1, 0).text='Subscribed BW'
    vr[num].cell(2, 0).text='Peak LAN'
    vr[num].cell(3, 0).text='Peak WAN-IN'
    vr[num].cell(4, 0).text='Peak WAN-OUT'
    vr[num].cell(5, 0).text='Recommended BW Capacity'
    vr[num].cell(7, 0).text='Peak Compression'
    vr[num].cell(9, 0).text='Optimized Traffic'
    vr[num].cell(10, 0).text='Optimized Traffic%'
    vr[num].cell(12, 0).text='Key Applications'
    vr[num].style ='TableGrid'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Key 'num' does not exist in your dictionary.

```
vr[str(num)] = document.add_table(rows=13, cols=(7))
```

here `num` is the integer `k`. It looks like you want to put the assignment inside the first loop.

In the second loop you try to assign to

```
vr['num']
```

Try:

```
vr[str(num)]
```

Note that for numbered indexing you are probably better off with a `list` or `array`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to remove the quotes around `num` in `vr['num']` as the string `"num"` is not a key in dict `vr`, and you should be using the string value of `num`:

```
for num in range(1,k+1):
    vr[str(num)].cell(1, 0).text='Subscribed BW'
    vr[str('num')].cell(2, 0).text='Peak LAN'
    ...
```

But, since you are using `num` only as a the key for your dict, there is no point in converting it to a string - you can just use it as an integer.

```
for num in range(1,k+1):
    vr[num].cell(1, 0).text='Subscribed BW'
    vr[num].cell(2, 0).text='Peak LAN'
    ...
```